# Raspberry Pi 3 + External HDD (HFS+) + Automount at boot

Tags: boot, mount, fstab

I want to use the external hdd with syncthing to synchronize the files on my external hdd with my other computers.
Therefore I try to get the pi to mount my external hdd (HFS+) at boot.

blkid (after manually powered external hdd up (via button)):

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="6BC0-19E3" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00008428-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p5: LABEL="SETTINGS" UUID="e6fbf66e-8a46-4be6-9a5a-bcbc08ea8d04" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00008428-05"
/dev/mmcblk0p6: LABEL="boot" UUID="1995-940D" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00008428-06"
/dev/mmcblk0p7: LABEL="root" UUID="6b8767e1-8014-43ba-9a7f-93a97d2ae785" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00008428-07"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="00008428" PTTYPE="dos"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="EFI" UUID="67E3-17ED" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI System Partition" PARTUUID="0581d89d-aedf-4108-be74-5640097df5c3"
/dev/sda2: UUID="aaa89a5f-39e7-30c5-9547-907311e17136" LABEL="backup" TYPE="hfsplus" PARTUUID="961322ef-ddfc-4ca3-8bc9-1bf039cb113b"
```

fstab (to mount /dev/sda2, my "backups" partition):

```
UUID=aaa89a5f-39e7-30c5-9547-907311e17136       /media/pi/backup        hfsplus defaults,users,nofail   0       0
```

blkid (directly after boot):

```
/dev/mmcblk0p1: LABEL="RECOVERY" UUID="6BC0-19E3" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00008428-01"
/dev/mmcblk0p5: LABEL="SETTINGS" UUID="e6fbf66e-8a46-4be6-9a5a-bcbc08ea8d04" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00008428-05"
/dev/mmcblk0p6: LABEL="boot" UUID="1995-940D" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="00008428-06"
/dev/mmcblk0p7: LABEL="root" UUID="6b8767e1-8014-43ba-9a7f-93a97d2ae785" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="00008428-07"
/dev/mmcblk0: PTUUID="00008428" PTTYPE="dos"
```

I am using a WD Elements 4 TB HDD with external power supply (was bundled with the hdd). If I reboot/power on the pi, the hdd spins up, but goes directly to sleep (i guess). I assume that is the case for raspbian not to mount the external hdd.

Is there a way to mount that external hdd properly at boot?

If I manually push the button on the hdd, raspbian mounts it automatically but only as read-only partition. Is there a way to customize this behavior and use fstab for this or maybe a cronjob+mount-command?

After I unmounted the read-only mounted partition, I mount it manually with `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/disk/by-uuid/aaa89a5f-39e7-30c5-9547-907311e17136 /media/pi/backup` which works as exspected.

I disabled automount already in `~/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/pcmanfm.conf` but the setting is ignored:

```
[config]
bm_open_method=0

[volume]
mount_on_startup=0
mount_removable=0
autorun=1

[ui]
always_show_tabs=0
max_tab_chars=32
win_width=943
win_height=653
splitter_pos=288
media_in_new_tab=0
desktop_folder_new_win=0
change_tab_on_drop=1
close_on_unmount=1
focus_previous=0
side_pane_mode=dirtree
view_mode=icon
show_hidden=0
sort=gicon;ascending;
toolbar=newtab;navigation;home;
show_statusbar=1
pathbar_mode_buttons=0
```